# Does mongodb support time triggered replication?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to set mongodb to start replicating itself at a certain point in time?  For example every Sunday at 3 a.m. replicate from one data center to another?

Comment: Perfect the delayed replica set members is exactly what I'm looking for - Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'll post my comment as answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with having a fixed, continuous delay (e.g. 1 day) between the two data centers, you should look into [delayed replica set members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/).

Otherwise, you can probably script that by disrupting the connection between the two data centers and restoring it when you want it to sync. But that doesn't sound great: you would need an oplog large enough to fit all the changes and make sure you don't end up with a primary on both sides.

Comment: If you have members of the same replica set in two data centres, breaking the connection should result in either a single primary (in the data centre which has a majority of configured voting nodes available) or no primary (if neither data centre has the majority of voting nodes required to elect and maintain a primary).